# Trying to display links depending on hover but It doesn't work(react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to display different links when user hovers different buttons (in react.js) but it doesn't work. It gives an error like this: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'datas[hovering].content'). Do you know what causes that? Here's my code:

Data I'm using:

```
const datas = [
     {title: "Home",content: [{name: "Home",to: "/"}, {name: "Abstract",to: "/#abstract"}],link: "/"},
     {title: "Project",content: [{name: "The Idea",to: "/Project#idea"}, {name: "Previous Similar Projects",to: "/Project#prev"}, {name: "Our Work",to: "/Project#work"}],link: "/Project"},
     {title: "Team",content: [{name: "Members",to: "/Team#members"}, {name: "Sponsors",to: "/Team#sponsors"}],link: "/Team"},
     {title: "Description",content: null,link: "/description"},
     {title: "Human Practices",content: [{name: "Collabrations",to: "/hp#collab"}, {name: "Integrated HP",to: "/hp#integrated"}],link: "/hp"},
     {title: "Judging Form",content: null,link: "/judging"},
     {title: "Gallery",content: null,link: "/gallery"}
]
```

My Component:

```
const SubLink: React.FC<{ name: string, to: string }> = function ({ name, to }) {
  return <li>
    <a onClick={() => closeNav()} href={to}>{name}</a>
  </li>
}
```

Initial declarations:

```
const [hovering, setHovering] = useState(0)
const [subs, setSubs] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([])
```

The useEffect Hook:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  const sublist = []
  for (var i=0;i<datas[hovering].content!.length;i++) {
    console.log(1)
    const data = datas[hovering].content![i]
    sublist.push(<SubLink key={i} name={data.name} to={data.to} />)
  }
  setSubs(sublist)
},[hovering])
```

Where I return the SubLink elements

````
<div className={styles.list}>
  {(() => {
    return (subs !== []) ? subs : <Image src="images/igem.png" alt="iGEM" style={{ height: "10rem" }} />
  })}
</div>
```
````

Comment: By the way don't be confused by the hierarchy(indents), just copy pasted it without no check

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the error is in the code you omitted. Something must presumably call `setHovering()`. If it sets it to a number larger than the length of the datas array then boom `datas[hovering]` is undefined

Comment: it is called somewhere else

Comment: I didn't put it in the code because it already works

Comment: And I'm sure that the problem is not there because it's initial value is 0, meaning that it takes the first element of the datas array to display.